# Unable to delete PostgreSQL role

Tags: postgresql, roles, privileges

Yesterday I created a user to make backups from PostgreSQL. I granted select to this user and then I noticed that the name was not well written. The problem is that I tried to erase the user using the command line and the response was, due to the grants that I made a few moments back:

> ```
> ERROR:  role "dump_user" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
> ```

Long story short, I erased this user using pgadmin and now I have problems because when I want to create a new table, it tells:

> ```
> ERROR:  role 313898229 was concurrently dropped
> ```

I cheked and 313898229 was the oid of this dump_user in the pg_authid table, I tried to create a new user and assign this oid, but postgres says that I can't modify system id "oid".

Is there a way that I can permanently erase this user?

Answer (score 0):

If all you wanted was [a different name](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html):

```
ALTER ROLE dump_user RENAME TO better_name;
```

Too late for that now. Before deleting the role you should have run:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY pg_dump TO postgres; -- postgres being default superuser role
```

Read details here:

- [Find objects linked to a PostgreSQL role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155332/find-objects-linked-to-a-postgresql-role/155356#155356)

Your error message:

> ERROR: role 313898229 was concurrently dropped

is defined [in the source code here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/113b0045e20d40f726a0a30e33214455e4f1385e/src/backend/catalog/pg_shdepend.c). Looks like a race condition between two transactions. But you omitted relevant details.